# Show for $D = 3$ that the group of units $\mathcal{O}^{\times}$ of $\mathcal O$ is infinite

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Here is the question I am trying to understand its solution:

Show for $D = 3,5,6$ and $7$ that the group of units $\mathcal{O}^{\times}$ of the quadratic integer ring $\mathcal O$ is infinite by exhibiting an explicit unit of infinite (multiplicative) order in each ring.

And here is the solution I found online:

> [image]

My question is:

1 - why using the lemma it suffices to find for each $D$ an element $a + b \sqrt{D}$ such that $a >1 $ and $b \geq 1$ and $N(a + b \sqrt{D}) = a^2 - b^2 D = 1$ and how actually the author found the $a$ and $b$ in each case?

Can someone clarify the answers to these questions for me please?

Comment: It's easier for people to answer if you limit yourself to one question per post.  The norm condition is used to (implicitly, as you note) ensure that each of the exemplary elements ($2 + \sqrt{3}$ in the case of $D = 3$) is a unit.  The lemma you include above (and the positivity of the coefficients of the exemplary elements) is used to show that the order of each exemplary unit is infinite.  How the author found the $a$ and $b$ in each case would be a good (single!) question to ask (it is possible that brute force was the "method").  Arguments like this do not really have unique "steps."

Comment: @leslietownes yes that is exactly what I was thinking about doing, I will delete the other 3 questions and maybe post another posts about them.

Comment: This lemma is quite unnecessary. All you have to do is observe that $2 + \sqrt{3} > 1$, so all of its powers have the same property, and same for the other units.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan what do you mean by all of its power have the same property?

Comment: I mean if $a > 1$ then $a^n > 1$ for all $n \ge 1$. In particular $a^n$ is never equal to $1$, so $a$ has infinite order.

Comment: How do we find the $a$ and $b$ say incase of $D = 5?$ I believe that is the most difficult one. @QiaochuYuan seems like you have a cleaner way of solving this problem in your mind.

Comment: For small values of $D$ you can just try out $a = 1, a = 2, \dots $ until you find an $a$ such that $b$ is an integer. In general this is the classical subject of Pell equations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) and you can find solutions by looking at the continued fraction of $\sqrt{D}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan so you are saying that the multiplicative infinite order is something very intuitive that does not need any lemma to be proved and if we just found a unit whose norm is greater than 1, then of course the norm of the increasing powers of this unit will also be greater than one. Am I correct?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan but what is the relation between the multiplicative order of the element and its norm?

Comment: Yes. I just explained the relation: if $a > 1$ then $a^n > 1$ for $n \ge 1$. Do you understand what I mean by this? Do you agree? Can you try out some examples?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am just confused is $a$ is the unit element or its norm?

Comment: I totally agree with your statement. I will try some examples if I understood exactly what is a. @QiaochuYuan

Comment: The unit element, or strictly speaking its embedding into $\mathbb{R}$ if you prefer to think of things that way. I mean that $2 + \sqrt{3}$ as a literal real number is greater than $1$, and so forth.

Comment: Ok, I think I see your point now. So we want two things a unit that is literally greater than 1 and we want its norm to be $\pm$1. That is the idea of the solution of this type of problems, am I correct? @QiaochuYuan

Comment: There are other ways to do it but this is the simplest argument to my mind.